# Is Pr(A | B, C) = Pr (A | B) * Pr(B | C)? If not, what assumptions do I need to establish it?

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability

I came across the following statement in a paper:

$$Pr(A | B, C) = Pr (A | B) * Pr(B | C)$$

A, B, C are discrete variable. Right before this, they say that this comes from the assumption that the distribution of A conditional on B does not vary by C, and they state it as:

$$Pr(A | B, C) = Pr (A | B)$$

How is it the case? Was it a typo in their paper? (In the paper, they are not in terms of A, B, C, but it is essentially this argument).

Comment: Could you please provide the name of the paper.

Comment: Sorry, how can the first and the second be compatible unless $P(B|C)=1$?

Comment: @ping, thats exactly my confusion. It must be a typo, or the assumption that they state is not what is needed.

Comment: Can you please link the paper?

Comment: Might make sense in a discussion of Markov Chains.

Comment: @BruceET that would make sense. It's difficult to tell without reference to the original paper.

Comment: https://ibb.co/DVNzzDd this is the relevant section. The objective is to obtain $Pr(I_{12}, R, C = 1 | I_2)$ from the paper's notation.

Comment: Welcome to CV, cosmia. This question would be *vastly* improved by heeding the (now third) call to provide a citation. I strongly encourage you to edit the question to add it.

Answer (score 2):

The only interpretation of their assumption that makes sense to me is that $Pr(A|B=b,C) = Pr(A|B=b)$, which is to say that for fixed $B$, $A$ does not depend on $C$.

Unlike what they have written, this doesn't conflict with the condition that $Pr(A|B,C) = Pr(A|B)Pr(B|C)$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is not true:
$Pr(A|B,C)=Pr(A|B)∗Pr(B|C) $

It is given that:
$Pr(A|B,C)=Pr(A|B)$

Therefor, the first equation can be written as:
$Pr(A|B)=Pr(A|B)∗Pr(B|C)$
Which means:
$Pr(B|C) = 1$
Which means one of:
a) $Pr(B) = 1$
b) $B = C$

This satisfies "the distribution of $A$ conditional on $B$ does not vary by $C$," but it doesn't explain, at all, why the author proceeds from the 2nd equation given to the 1st one.

I'm not going to get into an analysis of what could be changed where to make this make sense, under the assumption that there's a typo.